# How to compare JSON data against DB data in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to compare JSON response with DB data in JMeter. Below is Db table structure (Oracle database):

Table Structure

[image]

Below is the JSON

```
{
    "page": 2,
    "per_page": 6,
    "total": 12,
    "total_pages": 2,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Michael",
            "last_name": "Lawson",
            "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Lindsay",
            "last_name": "Ferguson",
            "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "email": "tobias.funke@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Tobias",
            "last_name": "Funke",
            "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/9-image.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "email": "byron.fields@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Byron",
            "last_name": "Fields",
            "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/10-image.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "email": "george.edwards@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "George",
            "last_name": "Edwards",
            "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/11-image.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "email": "rachel.howell@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Rachel",
            "last_name": "Howell",
            "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/12-image.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "support": {
        "url": "https://reqres.in/#support-heading",
        "text": "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"
    }
}
```

Below is the configuration I have made in JMeter

JDBC Request

[image]

JSON Extractor

[image]

Response Assertion

[image]

But I am getting null response:

Assertion Result

[image]

what mistake am I making?

I want to compare each cell data with JSON data. For example `ID=7` with JSON and `ID=9` with JSON and so on.

Is this possible to do this with any scripting language in JMeter, if yes please suggest the code for the same.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your setup:

1. You need to change your SQL query to `SELECT ID from HHDIXI.Data`, otherwise you will get `LAST_NAME` entries in the `ID` variable
2. You need to change your JSONPath query to `$..data[*].id` and set "Match No" to `-1` otherwise you will get only first ID into `idfromAPI` variable

   Use [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination to see what variables are being generated by the HTTP and JDBC request samplers.
3. If you want to compare each ID from API to each ID from the DB in one shot the only option is [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

   Example code:

   ```
   1.upto(vars.get('ID_#') as int, { index ->
       def expected = vars.get('ID_' + index)
       def actual = vars.get('idfromAPI_' + index)
       if (expected != actual) {
           AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
           AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Data mismatch, in the database: ' + expected + ', in the API: ' + actual)
       }
   })
   ```

   and demo:

   [image]

Comment: How can I add multiple conditions in the same example code like for last name, first name and email?